# PHP array + Mail several parts attached

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, shopping-cart, email-attachments

i'm french so excuse my accent. ;-)
I'm working on a PHP script ([based on AJAX Shopping Cart](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/shopping-cart-php-jquery/)) since many weeks and i can't find correct answer to my problem. I explain : I have a drag and drop basket to select pictures from an image bank. When user set his email and click a button, he receives by email his selection of pictures.

Here is my problem : if there is 3 pictures in the basket, he receives 3 emails with 1 picture by email. If there is 12 589 pictures ... 12 589 email !!

I hope someone could help me or explain me why it's wrong.

Here is my (part of) code :

```
<?php

//////////////////////////////////////
// From Drag and Drop
//////////////////////////////////////

$cnt = array();
$products = array();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
$key=(int)str_replace('_cnt','',$key);
$products[]=$key;
$cnt[$key]=$value;
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM internet_shop WHERE id IN(".join($products,',').")");

if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
{
echo '<h2>Votre sélection est vide. Mais comment êtes vous arrivé(e) ici ? </h2><a href="contact.php">contactez-nous</a>';
}
else
{
echo '<h2>Votre sélection vous a été expédié à <span style="color:#4FACC1;">'.$_POST ['email'].'</span>.</h2>
<br/>
<h2 style="color:#4FACC1;">Détails de votre sélection</h2>
';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

//////////////////////////////////////
// Display selection
//////////////////////////////////////

echo '';
echo '  <span style="float:left;margin:10px;text-align: center;">
        <img src="'.$row['chemin'].'/'.$row['img'].'" 
        alt="'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).'" 
        width="128" height="128" 
        class="pngfix" />
        <br/>
        '.$row['name'].'
        <b style="color:#4FACC1;font-size:9px;"> ('.$row['price'].' Ko)</b>
        </span>';
$total += $cnt[$row['id']] * $row['price'];

//////////////////////////////////////
// Variable
//////////////////////////////////////

$sujet_reportage = str_replace('/', ' : ', $row['chemin']);
$sujet_reportage = str_replace('_', ' ', $sujet_reportage);
$withpoutthunb = str_replace('thumb_', '', $row['img']);
$Photos = $row['chemin'].'/'.$withpoutthunb;
$selection = 'Votre sélection photo : '.$withpoutthunb;
$to = $_POST ['email'];
$from = "www.xxxxx.com"; 
$subject = $selection; 
$message = $sujet_reportage;
$headers = "From: $from";

//////////////////////////////////////
// array with filenames to be sent as attachment
//////////////////////////////////////

$files = array($Photos);

//////////////////////////////////////
// Frontière 
//////////////////////////////////////

$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

//////////////////////////////////////
// headers for attachment 
//////////////////////////////////////

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

//////////////////////////////////////
// multipart boundary 
//////////////////////////////////////

$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

//////////////////////////////////////
// preparing attachments
//////////////////////////////////////

for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
$file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
$data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
fclose($file);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";

if($x == (count($files)-1)) 
{
$message .= "–{$mime_boundary}–";
} 
else 
{
$message .= "–{$mime_boundary}\n";
}
}

//////////////////////////////////////
// send
//////////////////////////////////////

$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

//////////////////////////////////////
// End of while
//////////////////////////////////////

}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The call to `mail()` is within the while loop that is looking at each record.  What is your goal?  Do you want to send all pictures in 1 email?  Just build a message in the loop and once you get out of the loop, call mail().

Comment: consider using a mail library for PHP, there are quite a few to choose from, this will save you headaches later when your mail is being marked as spam, or other nuisances.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned use a library to make things easy on yourself:
http://swiftmailer.org/

And then you would create code like so with attachments:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

  // Give the message a subject
  ->setSubject('Your subject')

  // Set the From address with an associative array
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))

  // Set the To addresses with an associative array
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))

  // Give it a body
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')

  // And optionally an alternative body
  ->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')

  // Optionally add any attachments
  ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('my-document.pdf'))
  ;
```

**Reference:** http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

After making my own mail functions over the years, its really best to stick with a great library to do the work.

For your question, you would just repeat the attachment of the images:

```
->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('image1.jpg'))
->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('image2.jpg'))
->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('image3.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help ! I finally use the http://swiftmailer.org/ lib. And it works perfectly !

To send multi attached mail with swiftmailer, i do like this (post for those who search):

```
//////////////////////////////////////
// Appel de la librairie Mail
//////////////////////////////////////

require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

... votre appel en base (ou autre)

//////////////////////////////////////
// array with filenames to be sent as attachment
//////////////////////////////////////

$fichiers[] = $Photos;

//////////////////////////////////////
// DECLARE LES VARIABLES
//////////////////////////////////////

$mail = $_POST ['email'];
$from = "Your name"; 

//////////////////////////////////////
// Fermeture du while
//////////////////////////////////////


}

//////////////////////////////////////
// Construction du message
//////////////////////////////////////

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

//////////////////////////////////////
// Sujet du mail
//////////////////////////////////////

->setSubject('Votre sujet')

//////////////////////////////////////
// De
//////////////////////////////////////

->setFrom(array('xx@xxxx.com' => 'www.xxxx.xx'))

//////////////////////////////////////
// A
//////////////////////////////////////

->setTo($mail)

//////////////////////////////////////
// Contenu du mail
//////////////////////////////////////

->setBody($votre_contenu)

//////////////////////////////////////
// Contenu du mail (alternatif)
//////////////////////////////////////

->addPart('<q>'.$votre_contenu.'</q>', 'text/html')
;

//////////////////////////////////////
// Pieces jointes multiples
//////////////////////////////////////

foreach ($fichiers as $fichier)
{
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($fichier)) ;
}

//////////////////////////////////////
// Création du "moyen de transport"
//////////////////////////////////////

$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

//////////////////////////////////////
// Envoi du mail
//////////////////////////////////////

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$result = $mailer->send($message);

//////////////////////////////////////
// Réponse de l'envoi
//////////////////////////////////////

if($result)
{
echo '<h2>Votre sélection vous a été expédié à '.$_POST ['email'].'.</h2>
<br/>';
}
else
{
echo 'Erreur';
}
```

Thanks a lot for all !

Regards